# How can I use ssh multiplexing on windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, multiplexing

I am using remote - ssh on vscode to access a remote caen server. On WSL, I can use ssh multiplexing with the following config file:

Host *
ControlMaster auto
ControlPersist yes
ControlPath ~/.ssh/socket-%C
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 5

However, vscode doesn't seem to let me use a file on my WSL directory for my SSH host (or am I able to do this?). On windows, when I try to use this for ssh multiplexing on a windows ssh config file, remote - ssh on vscode says it can no longer establish a connection with caen. It works without the extra control and server lines.

Host caen
HostName myhostname
User myusename
ControlMaster auto
ControlPersist yes
ControlPath C:\Users\mycomputerusername.ssh\socketfile
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 5

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

I tried different controlpath filenames, accessing my wsl ssh config file with the remote - ssh on vscode, and a few other things. None worked.

Comment: It's unsupported in windows openssh build. see https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/405

Comment: Thank you. And was I correct that remote - ssh on vscode won’t be able to find my ssh config file in WLS, or is there a way to do that?